# " Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. " XAMPP MySQL Error

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I'm having an error with starting up MySQL from XAMPP, here are the two error screenshots, I have tried running as admin and changing the port but it has not worked.

[XAMPP Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEibR.png)

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn7ZT.png)

Comment: Have you tried to run XAMPP as as administrator?

Comment: zhje error log sjhows that a myssql server  is running without  a problem, at least that bit that you shown us. i am guessing you have two mysql server on the same port and the other is already started and running